# How to filter rows using DataTable.Select OR DataView.RowFilter on byte[] column?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that contains a column storing GUID as byte[]. I want to filter out rows based on this column. Any ideas, how we can do that?

```
//First column of the datatable is byte[] corresponding to the Raw(16) in oracle storing GUID.

DataTable myDataTable = GetAllInvoicesFromOracleDb(); 

Guid myRecordId = new Guid("8FAA05C8-4E14-447E-8FFA-DF4D3D5BD717");

DataRow[] foundRow = myDataTable.Select("Invoice_PK=" + myRecordId);//Invoice_PK is byte[] column and I have the GUID object
```

Comment: Why is Invoice_PL a `byte[]` rather than a `Guid` ?

Comment: Can't you just convert the byte array to a Guid?

Comment: Thanks for responses. Yes it is one approach that I am already doing. I am interested to know if filtering is possible on byte[] itself.